# XCode Projects not being pulled from source control correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have been using the following two github projects (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift and https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV) and have integrated them  with my application. However, when I push the changes to git, when someone else tries to pull from the application, the projects show up as empty and so then they have to re-add them to the project in order to work on the project. This problem constantly occurs when someone is pulling and I'm not too sure why. Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: I also have issues with pulling from source control. I can do a clean checkout, without issues. But if someone makes changes, and I perform a pull to update my local repo, Xcode randomly deletes build schemes. Yuk! Better off closing Xcode and falling back to the command line. Not a good workflow if you tell me...